# How do I put a constraint on a table to ensure only one boolean column across a subset of tables is true?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm wondering how I can constrain a particular boolean column to only be true for a certain subset of rows in a table.

in the example below rows with the same values for tuples `(id2, 1d3)` should only have one true in the default column:

```
$> SELECT * FROM records WHERE id2 = 2 AND id3 = 3;
$>   id  |  id2  |  id3  |  name  |  default
   ------+-------+-------+--------+---------
      1  |  2    |   3   |  bob   |  false
      2  |  2    |   3   |  jane  |  false
      3  |  2    |   3   |  jim   |  false
      4  |  2    |   3   |  cory  |  true
      5  |  2    |   3   |  alan  |  false


$> SELECT * FROM records WHERE id2 = 4 AND id3 = 5;
$>   id  |  id2  |  id3  |  name  |  default
   ------+-------+-------+--------+---------
      6  |  4    |   5   |  bill  |  false
      7  |  4    |   5   |  fred  |  false
      8  |  4    |   5   |  frank |  false
      9  |  4    |   5   |  dave  |  true
     10  |  4    |   5   |  ryan  |  false
```

Comment: I still don't see any "group" in your example. How can you distinguish one group from another?

Comment: I guess this is a bad example.  I should say results instead of groups

Comment: So what is the distinguishing attribute that makes one "result" different from the other?

Comment: there isn't in this example, I'll update it to reflect my situation more acurately, but I think your solution is going to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a partial unique index:

```
create unique index on records (id2, id3) where "default";
```

---

Note that `default` is a reserved word and thus a very bad choice for a column name.

Comment: I should mention that there may be more than one group whose default should be true

Comment: @BenGlasser There is no "group" in your question

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate table with one row that contains the mainOfferName of the row that you want. Then query as:

```
select yt.*, (nt.id is not null) as valueFlag from records yt left join
 newtable nt
 on yt.id = nt.id;
```

When you want to change the value, change the value in newtable.

Note: you can put the query into a view and read-only users will just work.

And, you could implement this with an `update` trigger on `records`. Instead of updating `records`, it would update newtable.

Comment: No need for a trigger, this can be achieved with a unique index